# UPDATE a varias filas mysql (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql

tengo la siguiente tabla **productos**:

```
|id_producto | unidades |
|   1        |    10    |
|   2        |    10    |
|   3        |    10    | 
|   4        |    10    |
```

Lo que yo hago es esto:

```
$bd->query("UPDATE productos set unidades=20 WHERE id_producto = 1");
$bd->query("UPDATE productos set unidades=30 WHERE id_producto = 2");
$bd->query("UPDATE productos set unidades=40 WHERE id_producto = 3");
$bd->query("UPDATE productos set unidades=50 WHERE id_producto = 1");
```

quisiera ver si estos 4 update los puedo unir en uno solo
e probado con esto:

```
$bd->query("UPDATE productos set a.unidades=20 , b.unidades=30,etc WHERE a.id_producto = 1, b.unidades=2,etc... ");
```

pero me muestra error obviamente porque ese codigo esta mal
de antemano gracias por su ayuda.

Nota:
**la pregunta puntual es: como puedo unir las 4 consultas UPDATE en una sola**

Comment: Hola. Desconozco si en la comunidad de Stackoverflow Español alguien haya preguntado lo mismo, sin embargo, buscando un poco en la comunidad en inglés, la misma pregunta se hizo hace 5 meses, la cual puedes revisar aquí https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432/multiple-updates-in-mysql Por lo que sugeriría que esta pregunta se cerrara por posible duplicidad.

Comment: Observa que hay una relación entre el id y la cantidad nueva.

Comment: @FernandoTorres esta pregunta no esta en español, gracias por tu enlace en ingles.

Comment: @Sal no entiendo tu comentario amigo

Comment: @IntruzO La pregunta que te proporcioné está en el idioma inglés, la cual fácilmente puedes traducir al español, en esta pregunta están planteando la misma duda que tienes, en la comunidad en español no han hecho antes, quizá, esta misma pregunta, sin embargo, mi punto es que no veo la necesidad de tener que responder a algo que ya se hizo en la misma comunidad, por lo que de nuevo, te invito a revisar el post y a solucionar el problema que estás teniendo, dentro de ella mucha gente ha compartido sus soluciones y aportado con explicaciones detalladas y técnicas que seguramente te ayudarán

Comment: Con aritmética básica puedes crear una generalización -o fórmula- para obtener la cantidad a partir del id.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías usar case, si son pocos updates

```
UPDATE productos SET unidades = CASE id_producto 
                          WHEN 1 THEN 20 
                          WHEN 2 THEN 30 
                          WHEN 3 THEN 40 
                          WHEN 4 THEN 50 
                        END 
             WHERE id_producto IN (1, 2, 3, 4);
```

Esto lo veo viables para lo que propones solo 4 registros y un solo campo. Si son muchos y muchos campos también se puede, pero escribir la instrucción puede ser de locos.
Si son muchos registros quizás fuera mejor borrar y luego insertar, pues la instrucción **INSERT** si acepta multiples filas en una sola operación.
**Amplío la respuesta**
La función CASE en MySQL es una sentencia condicional que se usa como selector. Según el valor de una variable o un campo se devuelve uno u otro valor. En este caso dependiendo del valor de id_producto se devuelve 20,30,40,50.
Podría leerla como "**cuando** ocurra esto **entonces** devolver este valor. Como ves es muy parecida a los swtich de los lenguajes de programación.

También se usa con condiciones individuales, por ejemplo

```
UPDATE productos SET unidades = CASE
                          WHEN  id_producto =1 THEN 20 
                          WHEN  id_producto =2 THEN 30 
                          WHEN  id_producto =3 THEN 40 
                          WHEN  id_producto =4 THEN 50 
                          ELSE  0
                        END 
             WHERE id_producto IN (1, 2, 3, 4);
```

En este caso se usan comparaciones en cada opción.
También se puede añadir la opción **ELSE** para un valor por defecto, es decir, que si no se cumple ninguna de las anteriores condiciones se devuelve 0 en este caso.

Comment: Hola, Juan, considera añadir más datos que aporten y retroalimenten técnicamente y/o teóricamente tu respuesta, afín de poder esclarecer el por qué propones que la pregunta se resuelva con tu respuesta, recuerda añadir enlaces, referencias, explicación técnica, etc. Saludos.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta pero podrias explicarla porfavor sobretodo eso del WHEN Y EL THEN